# How to Retrieve Main Menu Items from Drupal 7

Tags: web-services, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am trying to get Main Menu Names in Drupal 7, I have used below query but seems its not matching with Menu which are displaying on website.

> SELECT * FROM `menu_links` where menu_name='main-menu' and hidden=0
>   and mlid=p1  order by weight

Any suggestion? how to get Menu names from Druapl 7? 
Note : Druapl 7 based site has used TB Mega Menu for Menu.

Comment: What do you mean by "only main menu names", in Drupal you can't distinguish menu by types. Menus are menus and they are all together.
However I suspect you need "The links attached to <<main-menu>> menu", in this case your query will do the job.
If none of this are good explanation, please reformulate your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a [menu_get_names](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_names/7) function in the Drupal API. It returns an entire list of menu names.

Comment: Mario , I am trying to write custom web service using core php, so not sure how will able to use menu_get_names function? do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, I though you can access to the Drupal API.  "SELECT * FROM menu_links" returns valid results?

Comment: Yes its returning menu items, but returning many menu names, not only main menu names, do you have any link which i can refer to use drupal API? directly in mobile app , basically i am trying to show Drupal main menu names in mobile app